# Delphi XE config control

Tags: user-interface, delphi, controls, delphi-10.3-rio

Does anyone have an idea of what the control used by **Delphi XE** in the section (Options >Language >Formatter >Delphi >Indentation):
[image: (see this attached image)]

I can't find a native visual control in the palette that provides these variants...

- Is that a tree control with embedded editors?
- Otherwise, if it has to be coded, any little example or little idea how to build it?

Thank you for your contributions,

Comment: Are you sure that this is Delphi XE. Can you check the version please?

Comment: I'm sure :-D   ...about menu say: Embarcadero® Delphi 10.3 Version 26.0.36039.7899

Comment: Maybe its AddOn put here?  I installing CnPack and MMX tools...

Comment: @Yako: You are NOT using Delphi XE. You are using Delphi 10.3, which is a much newer version. Delphi XE was released in 2010. Delphi 10.3 was released in 2018. I can see from your initial screenshot that you are using 10.3, and your About box observation confirms this.

Answer (score 1):

Formatting and Modelling (if you have Architect edition) have been implemented as .Net libraries. Their settings pages use controls from [Windows Forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) library. Delphi has something similar only in third party libs. For example, after some tuning [Virtual Treeview](https://github.com/JAM-Software/Virtual-TreeView) can look like this.

Comment: And the control is called a `PropertyGrid`

Comment: @BlurrySterk buy this, isnt a native control from Delphi.